# Implement SAML SSO in Aspnetboilerplate with Angular as Frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I need to implement SAML SSO authentication in a https://aspnetboilerplate.com/ solution. In documentation not found a way to do or i'm not sure how to do, because i could not found any clear example. If you have an example of how to do this i will very grateful. It is worth mentioning that SAML is under Azure and i have data to configure in mi solution like application id, redirect urls, etc. but no TenantId (i mention this because many example ask for this parameter, is not my case)

According to what I have read, i need modify in aspnetboilerplate project my startup.cs class adding the SAML configurations, i have tried whith libraries such as: Sustainsys, Owin, AspNetSaml, Saml2, and others, but whitout good results because i have not found examples for aspnetboilerplate solution. Add to this, i have to modify the Angular proyect, same case, i have not clear examples to do in this type of solution.

Thanks in advance.